# Ubuntu Graphics Card boot issue

Tags: boot, grub2, graphics

I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 because Gimp wouldn't install on 11.10. Said some conditions were not fulfilled. I upgraded and the graphics went for a toss.  I was told by a friend to install the OpenGL drivers available on the nVIDIA website. I downloaded it and installed it then Ubuntu would not boot properly. Ubuntu always freezes up either at the login screen or the desktop. Sometimes it just hangs when I open the terminal. I reinstalled 11.10, again because I was told 12.04 had issues.

Now 11.10 will not load or has the same issues because of the graphic driver issues, I suppose. Now sometimes, on start up after the memory test, the screen just goes black with a blinking cursor on top. And I have no idea what to do with the Grub rescue. I am losing valuable time, unable to finish my work. I would appreciate it if someone could sort this out. Or atleast help me around with the grub rescue. How do I use that to fix the graphic issues?

My graphics card is a nVIDIA quadro fx 1500.

*edit* 
I have not yet installed the graphic drivers. The graphics were a little messed up when I had first installed ubuntu 11.10 but got worse after I updated it to 12.04. I re-installed 11.10 but the graphics are still as messed up. SO much so that I cannot even view the desktop if it finally does log me in.

Answer (score 0):

nVIDIA Drivers usually have issues with Ubuntu, and I don't know why.  I don't recommend installing the Graphic Drivers unless you know what you are doing or other experienced users told you to do so.

After you went on and reinstalled Ubuntu 11.10, does grub rescue show up before you even get to use Ubuntu 11.10?

If the answer is yes, read [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/153987/39869) to reinstall GRUB.

If the answer is no(that you messed up ubuntu yourself), then you would have to reinstall Ubuntu and remember not to install the Graphics card drivers.