# Bootloader of Ubuntu

Tags: grub2

I bought a HP laptop with windows 7. After I installed Ubuntu 15.04 desktop. But after restarting only it boot with windows 7 only. How can I get both Windows 7 and Ubuntu after booting the laptop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu won't boot with Windows7](http://askubuntu.com/questions/153986/ubuntu-wont-boot-with-windows7)

Comment: Use the boot-repair tool. see http://askubuntu.com/questions/153986/ubuntu-wont-boot-with-windows7

Answer (score 1):

You can do this rescuing [grub](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/GRUB) with live USB of [ubuntu](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Live-USB).

Just make a live usb/CD of your ubuntu version and run it in 'Try Now' mode. Then open the terminal and insert these commands in sudo mode :

Get appropriate sda of your ubuntu partition and then :

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc

sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sdX
grub-install --recheck /dev/sdX
update-grub

exit
sudo umount /mnt/sys
sudo umount /mnt/proc
sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts
sudo umount /mnt/dev
sudo umount /mnt
```

This should work, I guess.